# Simulating rain interference

Tags: homework, fading-channel

What fading model should I use for simulating rain loss in my network simulations? I am using NS-3 for this and I'm quite lost on how to go about this.

My simulation is just simple packet streaming and I want to test the effects of various interference on throughput.

Comment: What is NS-3? At what level are you simulating? The physical layer? Some higher level?

Comment: NS-3 is a network simulation framework. The way it works is that I can define a set of network devices, what wireless standard they use and the type of modulation they broadcast on. I am looking at interference caused to my simulated wireless channel and how it affects the bit error ratio of my connection. I can use propagation models in my simulation such as log distance and friis. But I want to know if any model exists for rain interference.